# Trying to exclude certain file types when using Visual Basic to copy directories

Tags: vb.net

I've written an application in visual basic that copies directories from the local drive to a network share, and that portion works perfectly, but now I want to exclude certain file types from being copied in the directory and the sub-directories and I'm not quite sure how to go about doing that. Here is my code if it helps you answer my question. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
Public Class Choices

    Private Sub Choices_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    End Sub

    Public Sub btnDocuments_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDocuments.Click


        Dim docsDirectory, destdocsDirectory, userDirectory, userName, hDrive, mydocsDirectory, destmydocsDirectory, newdestdocsDirectory As String
        'Function to pull user profile path
        hDrive = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("homedrive")
        userName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("username")
        userDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile")
        docsDirectory = userDirectory + "\Documents"
        destdocsDirectory = hDrive + userName + "\My Files"
        mydocsDirectory = "C:\My Documents"
        destmydocsDirectory = hDrive + userName + "\My Documents"


        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(destdocsDirectory)) Then

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(docsDirectory, destdocsDirectory, showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)

        Else
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(destdocsDirectory)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(docsDirectory, destdocsDirectory, showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)

        End If


        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(mydocsDirectory)) Then

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(mydocsDirectory, destmydocsDirectory, showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)

        Else
            MessageBox.Show(mydocsDirectory + "Does not exist")
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDesktop_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDesktop.Click
        Dim deskDirectory, destdeskDirectory, userDirectory, userName, hDrive As String
        hDrive = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("homedrive")
        userName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("username")
        userDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("userprofile")
        deskDirectory = userDirectory + "\Desktop"
        destdeskDirectory = hDrive + userName + "\Desktop"
        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(deskDirectory)) Then

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(deskDirectory, destdeskDirectory, showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)

        End If


    End Sub




End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea (remember to import System.IO):

```
    If (My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists(destdocsDirectory)) Then
        For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(docsDirectory, _
                FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, "*.*")
            Select Case LCase(Path.GetExtension(foundFile))
                Case ".mks"

                Case ".wav"

                Case ".jpg"

                Case ".wmv"

                Case Else
                    My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(foundFile, destdocsDirectory & "\" & Path.GetFileName(foundFile))
            End Select
        Next
    Else
```

Comment: Hmm I'll give that a shot but what If I'm wanting to filter out more than one file type. Because basically due to space restrictions on my network share I'm wanting to keep out all video, audio, and picture file types such as, .wav, ,jpg, .png, .wmv, etc.

Comment: added `select case` to handle multiple exlusions, see above

Comment: Then after the next is where I put my code to copy the directory right:

Next
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(deskDirectory, destdeskDirectory, showUI:=FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)
        End If

Comment: Dont need to add that line. Files are already copied with `My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(...)`

Comment: Now I have another question what if I want to run this program again so i can do a incremental back up so I keep the files that I have copied already, but copy anything that isn't located on the destination directory from the source directory and copy any files that are on the destination directory from the source directory that  have a newer modify date.

Comment: I changed the SearchTopLevelOnly to SearchAllSubDirectories and now I'm getting an error that says An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional Information:Access to the path C:\Users\"username"\Documents\My Music' is denied.